# Creating new dataframes for each level of a categorical variable (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a categorical variable with 3 different levels. Each level of the variable refers to a different group (Small,Medium,Large).

I would like to create new data frames for each of these levels.One for small, one for medium and one for large.

I tried to do this with the below code...

group1=data([data["categorical_variable"]=="Small"])

However, I get the below error message and I am not sure why I am seeing this?

**AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'convert_objects'**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what is recommended here is to use [`DataFrame.GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and save in a dictionary

```
groups = dict(data.groupby("categorical_variable").__iter__())

#print(groups['Small'])
#print(groups['Medium'])
```

if you really want three separate variables, note `sort=True` in `GroupBy`

```
 large_df, medium_df, small_df = tuple(df for _, df in data.groupby("categorical_variable"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
small_df = data.loc[data["categorical_variable"]=="Small", :]
medium_df = data.loc[data["categorical_variable"]=="Medium", :]
large_df = data.loc[data["categorical_variable"]=="Large", :]
```

Comment: this is slow 
and not recommended

Comment: I'd agree if there were lots fo variables but for three I think this approach is fine and obvious to what is going on. Also, it should be more familiar to the OP as it is the approach he was trying to take.

Comment: It is not necessary to create a dictionary, we can also assign it to independent dataframes in a line with groupby .... The approach with loc takes more lines, and is not scalable

Comment: As I said, I agree. This is just another approach that may make sense to the OP if he is new to pandas.

Comment: in my opinion this is a bad practice that should not be learned